# pixel format not accelerated in jmonkeyengine 3

Tags: jmonkeyengine

Instaled jmonkeyengine 3.1.0 stable SDK
create new project.basic game.then run default main.java like hello world application.but gor error:
failed to create display.
Pixel format not accerated
Org.lwjgl.opengl.windowspeerinfo.nchoospixelformat(native method)

I tried google .some driver problem.how to solve this problem.
What is opengl 1,2
Why not start output display.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the forum for the issue and found this thread:
https://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/odd-pixel-format-not-accelerated-problem-win-10/37849/16

It recommends downgrading the graphics (nvidia) drivers.

"I finally got the solution ! If you have a Nvidia card and you get this error you need to downgrade your driver to the previous version.
Device Manager -> Graphics Cards -> Properties -> Driver -> Previous version..."